# hashtag double query?

Tags: javascript, dom, backbone.js, hashtag

I'm using **backbone.js** to route and bind events to DOM elements. Events trigger and JSON is fetched from the server.

Typically, clicking on an item would send a POST request to the server with the item's `id` attribute.

However, I would like the hash in the url to display `#item_name` instead of `#id`

If  the user hits the back button or accessed the page directly, I would only have the  `#item_name`, is there a way to avoid doing a double query in this case. (querying for the item id first then the actual query)

If not would this significantly affects the performance of a direct link page load?

Answer (score 0):

If you like this to work your item_name has to be unique in the database. So it is already a sort of id. In Backbone you can set the property that should be use as item id for every model.

```
Backbone.Model.prototype.idAttribute = 'some_model_property';
```

In your case you would have to call something like:

```
Item.Model.prototype.idAttribute = 'item_name';
```

If you now are using model function like load() or save() Backbone is going to build the items url with the item_name instead of the id.

```
POST to /item/item_name
GET /item/item_name
```

In addition to that you can now fetch those models from the collection by their item_names:

```
var model = myCollection.get(item_name);
```

The only problem is that you can have only one id attribute for a model. So you will loose the ability to use the actual id as id property for those models.

Comment: aye, thanks! i think i'll do the double calls after all since, when i do .navigate(), it'll be doing a call using the #id. thanks!